# How to compare each row from one dataframe against all the rows from other dataframe and calculate distance measure?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have two different customer dataframes and I would like to match them based on Jaccard distance matrix or any other method.

df1

```
 Name     country            cost
    0    raj  Kazakhstan     23
    1    sam      Russia     243
    2  kanan     Belarus     2
    3    Nan         Nan     0
```

df2

```
   Name     country   DOB
0   rak  Kazakhstan   12-12-1903
1   sim      russia   03-04-1994
2   raj     Belarus   21-09-2003
3  kane     Belarus   23-12-1999
```

Output:

if the string comparison value is greater than >0.6, 
I would like to combine both the rows in the new dataframe.

Df3

```
    Name     country   Name  country     cost   DOB
0    raj  Kazakhstan   rak   Kazakhstan  23     12-12-1903
1    sam      Russia   sim   russia      243    03-04-1994
2  kanan     Belarus   Kane  Belarus     2      23-12-1999
```

I had tried doing calculating each row against each row but don't how to compare each rows against entire rows from one to other dataframe?

Comment: What are you looking to get from this bounty? Specifically, what about the currently accepted answer aren't you happy with?

Comment: To compare the distance between column1 from table 1 against column1 from table 2 and distance between column2 from table 1 against column2 from table 2 and so on. Finally take an average scores from two comparisons.

Comment: Seems a bit too broad if you ask me. Where is your attempt?

Comment: it is better just open a new question about your follow up question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like using `fuzzywuzzy`

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

df1['key'] = df1.sum(1)
df2['key'] = df2.sum(1)


def yoursource(x):
    if [process.extract(x, df2.key.tolist(), limit=1)][0][0][1]>60:
        return [process.extract(x, df2.key.tolist(), limit=1)][0][0][0]
    else :
        return 'notmatch'

df1['key'] = df1.key.apply(yoursource)
```

---

After that we get the match key using `merge`

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='inner').drop('key',1)
df
  Name_x   country_x Name_y   country_y
0    raj  Kazakhstan    rak  Kazakhstan
1    sam      Russia    sim      russia
2  kanan     Belarus   kane     Belarus
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to merge the different columns presented in the different dataframes? For example, I have 3 columns in df1 and 5 columns in df2. I wanted to compare only 2 columns but I want to add all the columns in the new dataframe

Comment: @Raj change this part df1['key']=df1[['col1','col2']].sum(1)
df2['key']=df2[['col1','col2']].sum(1)

Comment: Is there a possibility of calculating and comparing each cell value of  row data from one data frame against other data frame and find which row value is greater than 0.6 in average  ?